# Not getting <div> tag contents in javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

**Javascript Code In First ContentPlaceHolder :-**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function PrintElem(elem) {
        alert(elem);
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }
    function Popup(data) {

        var mywindow = window.open('', 'Loan Approve Details', 'height=400,width=600');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Loan Inquiry Details</title>');
        /*optional stylesheet*/ //mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;
    }
</script> 
</asp:Content>
```

**Source Code in second ContentPlaceHolder :-**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
      <div id="mydiv">
       <table>
          //here is lots of textbox and other controls
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="PrintElem('#mydiv')"
             CausesValidation="False" />
       <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" 
                                    CausesValidation="False" />
       </table>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Code Behind :-**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myscript", "PrintElem('#mydiv')",true);
}
```

**Explanation :-**
Here my problem is that when I call **PrintElem(elem)** function from source code then it works properly but when I call **PrintElem(elem)** function from code behind then I am not getting any value of **div** in **$(elem).html()** even I am getting same id value in **alert(elem)** so please help me to solve this problem.And I actually want to print all contents of **div** tag after execution of some code in code behind.so I am trying something like this.

Comment: please write your javascript code on document.ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute a script when the page finishes loading:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myscript", "PrintElem('#mydiv')",true);
        }
```